# (Flash) Why on(release) and on(rollover) is not work correctly?

Tags: flash, actionscript

I'm rookie in flash action script, My problem is when I try to use on(rollover) and on(release) together on(rollover) is working but on(release) is not work!! 
this is my script.

```
on(rollOver){
    gotoAndStop(5);
}
on(rollOut){
    gotoAndStop(1);
}
on(release){ 
    loadMovie("Lesson1(Menu).swf", 0);
}
```

but when I use only `on(release)` it work properly.

Comment: Why you think it is not working correctly?

Comment: Because when I use on(release) with on(rollover) it working only on(rollover) but on(release) is not working.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your rollOver is being triggered when the mouse enters whatever clip you are describing, and you do not have a correct on(release)-code in frame 5, which it is in when the onRelease is triggered with your mouse click.

Note that the syntax you are using is very outdated.